# Header appears on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I was working on a project that had a different header appear for when the page is scrolled past the main one.

Here's a fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/a7tLdsov/3/

Could anyone explain how to make this work? I thought that this js would make it work but it still isn't quite there.

Thanks,

```
:)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making these changes:

Change

```
$("body").scroll
```

to

```
$(window).scroll
```

and change

```
document.getElementById('transhead').style.display = "visible";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('transhead').style.display = "block";
```

Make sure jQuery is added as a framework in your fiddle.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hba9twcd/